# How to share the folder with ms word in ios?

Tags: ios, ms-office, shared-data

I need to integrate work with ms office in my application. I use the article https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn911482.aspx, but when you send a file to url, ms word can not access it :(

For send I use: canOpenUrl/openUrl. Url string is: 
**ms-word:ofe|u|/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/85D7E895-0F0D-4BBF-B83A-41122B6A73E4/Documents/documents/doc_0_148856.docx|p|app_ms_return|c|doc_148856**
So I tried to implicitly and explicitly specify the protocol:
**ms-word:ofe|u|file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/85D7E895-0F0D-4BBF-B83A-41122B6A73E4/Documents/documents/doc_0_148856.docx|p|app_ms_return|c|doc_148856**
I think that MS Word does not have access to file, but I do not know how to give it to him :(

Help pls :)

P.S.
There may be some other solution for transmission of file in MS Word, in addition to opening up access?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of integration only works with files hosted in SharePoint or OneDrive. From that URL:

> You can enable users who are running Office on an iOS device to open
>   and edit files stored in SharePoint or OneDrive from any application (...)